# Import CSV, match Birthdate for todays date and export all matching rows

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I need to filter CSV files for birthdays. So all Rows of matching birthdays should be exported to a new CSV file.

File is like this:

```
MSISDN;Kunden Anrede;Kunde Vorname;Kunden Nachname;Kunde Stra§e;Kunde PLZ;Kunde Stadt;E-Mail Adresse;Geburtstag Kunde;PKK;Kundennummer;Vertrag;Shop;Aktivierungsdatum
123456789;Herr;Max;Mustermann;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;26.07.1980;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016
123456789;Herr;John;Doe;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;26.08.1990;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016
123456789;Herr;Max;Mustermann;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;20.08.1993;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016
```

Here it my code:

```
function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$inputfile = Get-FileName "C:\temp"
$sOutFile = "C:\output.csv" # Change to your actual path

Import-Csv $inputfile -Delimiter ';' | where {
    $_."Geburtstag Kunde" -like "$((Get-Date).Day).$((Get-Date).Month)*"
} | % echo
```

It lets me pick the input file but I don't get an echo of the matching files. Also I want to write the output to the same file but with -birthdays attached.

Guess I have to work with for each loops.

Comment: What does `Import-Csv $inputfile -Delimiter ';' | where {$_."Geburtstag Kunde" -like 
"$((get-date).Day).$((get-date).Month)*"}` returns?

Comment: and you can shorten `"$((get-date).Day).$((get-date).Month)*"` a bit to `"$((Get-Date).ToString('dd.MM*'))"`

Comment: does the file picker have ANYTHING to do with your actual question? if not, **_please_** remove everything that does NOT pertain the the problem. ///// also, please post the 1st few lines of your CSV file so that folks can compare that to your code. right now the code DOES NOT match the headers you list.

Comment: Well the code as it is doesnt return anything, even if I add a line with todays date to test the filter.

Comment: @user4916097 - Post *(part)* of the **unaltered** csv, including headers. As Lee says, you filter on `Geburtstag Kunde` but you post `Birthday`... wich is it?

Comment: I added the csv

Comment: @user4916097 - thank you for adding the info! [*grin*] ///// you say `an echo of the matching files.` ... but your code is set to send out matching _rows_ from that one file. please add the desired output from the input you posted.

Comment: It should output:  MSISDN;Kunden Anrede;Kunde Vorname;Kunden Nachname;Kunde Stra§e;Kunde PLZ;Kunde Stadt;E-Mail Adresse;Geburtstag Kunde;PKK;Kundennummer;Vertrag;Shop;Aktivierungsdatum
123456789;Herr;Max;Mustermann;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;26.07.1980;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016     so I can echo it to a new csv

Comment: @user4916097 - if you want to reply to a person, use `@` as the 1st character of your comment and then the 1st few chars of their user id. [*grin*]

Comment: @user4916097 - please, put the info in your Original Post so that others can find it without needing to dig thru the comments.

Comment: You have a formatting issue. The `(Get-Date).Month` returns `7` but your csv contains `07`. That might be all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a formatting issue. Your CSV contains trailing zero's for the month but your where clause ommits these.

If you change your where clause to `where {$_."Geburtstag Kunde" -like "$((Get-Date).ToString('dd.MM*'))"}`, it works as expected

**Test code**

```
@'
MSISDN;Kunden Anrede;Kunde Vorname;Kunden Nachname;Kunde Stra§e;Kunde PLZ;Kunde Stadt;E-Mail Adresse;Geburtstag Kunde;PKK;Kundennummer;Vertrag;Shop;Aktivierungsdatum;
123456789;Herr;Max;Mustermann;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;26.07.1980;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016;
123456789;Herr;John;Doe;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;26.08.1990;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016;
123456789;Herr;Max;Mustermann;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;20.08.1993;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016;
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' | where {$_."Geburtstag Kunde" -like "$((Get-Date).ToString('dd.MM*'))"}
```

Answer (score 1):

presuming you want the full row of data that was in the CSV for any row where the date matches today, this otta work ... [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
MSISDN;Kunden Anrede;Kunde Vorname;Kunden Nachname;Kunde Stra§e;Kunde PLZ;Kunde Stadt;E-Mail Adresse;Geburtstag Kunde;PKK;Kundennummer;Vertrag;Shop;Aktivierungsdatum
123456789;Herr;Max;Mustermann;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;26.07.1980;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016
123456789;Herr;John;Doe;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;26.08.1990;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016
123456789;Herr;Max;Mustermann;Blabla;78999;Stadt;mail@mail;20.08.1993;1999;999999999;Bla;Bla;02.02.2016
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

# this gets the date info with the time set to midnite
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$TodayDateString = $Today.ToString('dd.MM')

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    if (($IS_Item.'Geburtstag Kunde' -replace '\.\d{4}', '') -eq $TodayDateString)
        {
        $IS_Item
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
MSISDN            : 123456789
Kunden Anrede     : Herr
Kunde Vorname     : Max
Kunden Nachname   : Mustermann
Kunde Stra§e      : Blabla
Kunde PLZ         : 78999
Kunde Stadt       : Stadt
E-Mail Adresse    : mail@mail
Geburtstag Kunde  : 26.07.1980
PKK               : 1999
Kundennummer      : 999999999
Vertrag           : Bla
Shop              : Bla
Aktivierungsdatum : 02.02.2016
```

you can use `Export-CSV` to send the `$Results collection out to a CSV file.